# GalaSoft.MvvmLight.EventToCommand<T> args always null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a base class derived from MvvmLight.ViewModelBase with additional responsibilities to handle object selections.  This class defines a `RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>` property which is bound in the View:

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <galaxcmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectCommand,Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This view is used multiple times inside a containing view that I now need to handle mousedowns too.  My issue arises because I don't want the container to handle mousedown if it was handled by a contained view.  I thought the PassEventArgsToCommand was my solution to this problem because I planned a child VM to just set `MouseButtonEventArgs.Handled = true`.  Unfortunately, the MouseButtonEventArgs argument is always null.  Just in case, I also tried RoutedEventArgs and even EventArgs, but they're all null too.

What am I doing wrong with EventToCommand (or EventTrigger?)?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/) a modified `EventToCommand` implementation - based on the Galasofts one - where you can set the `Eventargs` as `CommandParameter` and stop event routing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The enhancement you link to is based on an older version of EventToCommand before PassEventArgsToCommand was introduced and is trying to achieve the same goal. I'm hoping to gain insight into what's wrong with my current understanding, but if I can't solve it I'll look down the modify route.